# Flickr API iOS app "POST size too large!"

Tags: http, ios, post, flickr

I am trying to send a photo from an iOS app to Flickr using the API. I have successfully got the authorisation working and have a token ready to use. I am sending the photo data over a HTTP POST and am following the formatting guide here.

http://www.flickr.com/services/api/upload.example.html

But the response I get back from the API is...

```
<err code="93" msg="POST size too large! Try something smaller, mmkay?" />
```

I have read that it may have something to do with the boundary's. I've doubled checked regarding @samrowlands comments on this post. http://www.flickr.com/groups/api/discuss/72157605534260892/

Any help would be great. Thanks!

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"photo.jpg"];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.9);

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.flickr.com/services/upload/"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------7d44e178b0434"];

[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary] forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type:"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"api_key\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", apiKey] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"auth_token\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", apiToken] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"api_sig\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSString *uploadSig = [self md5HexDigest:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@api_key%@auth_token%@", apiSecret, apiKey, apiToken]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", uploadSig] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo\"; filename=\"photo.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:imageData];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];
```

Comment: Can you tell me how you managed the authorization process. I am just starting with it, and I am reluctant to use objectiveFlickr framework.

Answer (score 3):

I got this to work by making the change to Content-Type(no colon) and adding a boundary after the sig and before the photo. Thanks for the code - hope this helps.

```
NSString *uploadSig = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@api_key%@auth_token%@", secret, api_key, auth_token] MD5];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.flickr.com/services/upload/"];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------7d44e178b0434"];

[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary] forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"api_key\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", api_key] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"auth_token\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", auth_token] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"api_sig\"\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", uploadSig] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo\"; filename=\"photo.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:imageData];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];
```

Comment: I'm getting a invalid auth token message with using this code. Error 98.This is my code that calculates the upload sig: http://pastie.org/4355056

Comment: any updates on this  ? I am also facing the same issues