# sending a pdf file from iphone to web server using AFNetworking?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

The following code are to send an image file to web server but I need to change it to send a pdf file. Where to change I have no idea. Any help..

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api-base-url.com"];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar.jpg"], 0.5);
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/upload" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"avatar" fileName:@"avatar.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
}];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
    NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
}];
[httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this link . I think this what you would need . But first you have to store the PDF file in the documents directory.

[Upload pdf file (from document directory) through web service in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399542/upload-pdf-file-from-document-directory-through-web-service-in-iphone)

This code uses [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Not sure if it's error free, because it has been taken from a longer source, so I've modified some pieces of code, but it's a good start

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

NSData is for storing data generally, not just images. If you create a NSData object containing PDF data instead then you will able to use the same code to upload it. You don't have to have the PDF file in a specific place as long as you can access it - though `dataWithContentsOfFile` will do fine if you do have a file. Many apps create PDF output from ther own displays using a PDF graphics context for instance, with `UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData`.

Here's [some code](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/606) showing how to send the PDF using AFNetworking (see this for correct mime type etc.) - that snippet is being used to illustrate a bug in AFNetworking, but don't worry about that, it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your pdf file into NSData and send it to web service

You simply need to do this:

```
NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfName];
```

You can have a web service that will take this data and convert it back to PDF at server side.