# CouchDB / iOS - Send HTTP POST request with a image

Tags: iphone, ios, couchdb

I have google'd and searched around for a solution but I can't find much.

I need to send a HTTP POST request from objective-c to my couchdb. 
What I need to know is how to add an image to the request in objective-c, and preferably a link to a library/framework which simplifies the while process of sending requests from iOS.

I Have found a couple of frameworks, but one was no longer in development and the other had not been updated in a year.

Anyone have any experience on this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ios Upload Image and Text using HTTP POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564833/ios-upload-image-and-text-using-http-post)

Comment: did you try ASIHttpRequest? It has an api to upload the image and is very optimized one.

Comment: ASIHttpRequest is no longer in development though, perhaps it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on something similar, I use the AFNetworking library to post to a php script
which then puts it into a Mysql database.

It should be much simpler in your case because you can post directly to couchDB
The AFNetworking library has examples that should do just what you need.

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Getting-Started-with-AFNetworking