# Upload an image file with POST

Tags: ios, web-services, post

I'm trying to send an UIImage and some extra parameters through POST.

I've tried the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564833/ios-upload-image-and-text-using-http-post) with no success:

The HTML form equivalent would be the following (it works):

```
<form method="POST" action="UploadURL" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="pic">
   <input type="submit" value="upload">
   <input type="hidden" name="param1" value="param1value"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="param2" value="param2value"/>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error did you get with the other question's code?

Comment: @RichardBrown "Permission denied to access this resource." That's the message from the API.

Answer (score 0):

I've just wasted so many hours... It seems that the people I've been working with gave me a wrong URL, which gives the same response for anything. I've just wasted so many hours on this.

Please refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564833/ios-upload-image-and-text-using-http-post) for a good answer for uploading images using POST request.

Comment: It happens. I was once given a `192` address from a client in Asia.