# Upload image to Web Service

Tags: ios, image, base64, asmx

Ok, so I have this web service that uses a user's email & password and has to convert an image to a base64 string and then upload through a asmx service.
Any clues on how to accomplish this?
I have to do this through an iOS/xcode app.
I was trying this code

```
- (IBAction)uploadImage:(NSData *)imageData filename:(NSString *)filename{
 NSString *fullURL = @"www.example.com/asmx/imageupload.asmx";
 NSURL *urlString= [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:urlString];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",filename]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[self uploadImage:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 1.0) filename:image];
};
```

Comment: The solution is described here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564833/ios-upload-image-and-text-using-http-post

Comment: @gagarwal, How do I use that solution, I ended up getting about 12 errors, when I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

i used this code for registration :

```
    NSString *str=RegisterWebService;//call your webservice
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];


    //parameter a data of image
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"a.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imgProfile.image, 60);//put your image here
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imgData]];
    [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //  parameter username

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uname\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[userName.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    //  parameter e-Mail
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"email\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[eMail.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // parameter passWord
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"pass\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[passWord.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // close form
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
    [request setHTTPBody:body];


    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *returnData, NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@" data length :%d", returnData.length);

         NSDictionary *dict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];

         if ([[dict valueForKey:@"Status"] integerValue]==1 )
         {
             //check your web-service response do your stuff here
         }

     }];
```

May it will help to you.

Happy coding...:)