# ios text upload via multipart HTTP request

Tags: ios, http-post, nsurlconnection

I am trying to upload a text using `multi-part form encoding` in iOS.

**What i Did** :

I have tried via the info provided in the [ios Upload Image and Text using HTTP POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564833/ios-upload-image-and-text-using-http-post).

**Problem** :

I put log in server side, And here is what did i receive from my IOS App.

No problem with `key` Name. But, I receive the `value` as `null`

```
"443" "POST" "/api/private/json/" "content=null&scope=null&action=null&documentname=null&apikey=null"
```

**My code** :

```
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [params setObject:@"XXXXX" forKey:@"apikey"];
    [params setObject:@"DataAPI" forKey:@"scope"];
    [params setObject:@"push" forKey:@"action"];
    [params setObject:docName forKey:@"documentName"];
    [params setObject:content forKey:@"content"];
    [params setObject:authToken forKey:@"authtoken"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
    [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:30];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    // set Content-Type in HTTP header
    NSString *boundary = @"V2ymHFg03ehbqgZCaKO6jy";

    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];



    // add params (all params are strings)
    for (NSString *param in params) {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [params objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    }

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
    [request setHTTPBody:body];
    NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:body encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    NSLog(@"%@",myString);
    // set the content-length
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    // set URL
    [request setURL:url];


    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *POSTReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
    NSString *theReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[POSTReply bytes] length:[POSTReply length] encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Reply: %@", theReply);
```

I couldn't able to understand the issue, Whether it is from server side or from my code.

Thanks for sharing your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix it:

Instead of:

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

write

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

(the terminating CRLF is optional)

Please note if you write this:

```
for (NSString *param in params) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: text/plain\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [params objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

that everything before the boundary-delimiter, e.g. `\r\n--<boundary>` conceptually belongs to the *data*, e.g. to the parameter value.

Likewise, the preceding `CRLF` of a "dash-boundary" (`--<boundary>`) belongs to the delimiter.

Conceptually, the *first* delimiter MUST also start with a CRLF:

```
`CRLF--<boundary>`
```

however, it seems NSURLConnection already puts a CRLF *after* the message headers. So we end up having this:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="xyz"CRLF
<other header>CRLF
CRLF             <-- added by NSURLConnection, which is debatable if this is correct
... multipart body starts here
```

Any bytes *after* the headers and *before* the start of multipart shall be ignored by the server. This kind of junk is called `preamble`:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="xyz"CRLF
<other header>CRLF
<preamble bytes>CRLF--xyz
                ^~~~~~~~~ delimiter
....
```

`preamble` may be empty or it may contain any number of CRLFs, for example.

The `body-part`, which consists of MIME headers and the part body-data, follows after the boundary, but strictly not immediately:

```
<preamble-bytes>CRLF--xyz<transport-padding>CRLF<body-part> 
                ^~~~~~~~~ delimiter             ^~~~~~~~~~~ MIME headers and data
```

where `<transport-padding>` is any number of spaces or horizontal tabs, that is, it may be empty.

This all means, that we should be able to use the following line as a non-terminating delimiter (for the first and any subsequent non-terminating boundary-delimiter) plus a CRLF:

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Then the `body-part` immediately follows (starting with headers, then the data):

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: text/plain\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", key] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", (self.parameters)[key]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

These four lines can be used in a loop for each parameter.

The terminating delimiter can be added as follows:

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

A terminating CRLF is optional. Any bytes following the last CRLF belong to the `epilogue` and shall be ignored by the server.

See: RCF 2046 http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2046.txt.

Answer (score 1):

You are not appending the terminating boundary.

This:

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Should look like this:

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

**EDIT:**

You are missing some more things actually. You are not setting the content type for the data and you're missing some new lines.

Your loop should look like this:

```
for (NSString *param in params) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: text/plain\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [params objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

**EDIT2:**

Here's an example server-side code which is handling that same request correctly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import web

urls = ("/", "Index")
app = web.application(urls, globals())

class Index(object):
    def POST(self):
        x = web.input()
        print x
        print x['apikey']
        print x['scope']
        return 'success'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Output:

```
<Storage {'scope': u'asd', 'apikey': u'123\r\n'}>
123

asd
127.0.0.1:60044 - - [02/Dec/2013 15:02:55] "HTTP/1.1 POST /" - 200 OK
```

And sample console app. which you can compile with clang - `clang -framework Foundation test_post.m -o test_post`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Uploader : NSObject <NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *parameters;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURLConnection *connection;

@end

@implementation Uploader

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSMutableURLRequest*)createRequest {
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8080/"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *boundary = @"0xB0un9ArY";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:@"1.0" forHTTPHeaderField:@"MIME-Version"];
    [request setValue:@"keep-alive" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Connection"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    for (NSString *key in [self.parameters allKeys]) {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: text/plain\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", key] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", (self.parameters)[key]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    return request;
}

- (void)upload {
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self createRequest];
    self.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (self.connection) [self.connection start];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse*)response {NSLog(@"connection:didReceiveResponse: %@", response);} 
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data {NSLog(@"connection: didReceiveData: %@", data);} 
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didFailWithError:(NSError*)error {NSLog(@"connection: didFailWithError: %@", error);}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection { NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading:"); }
@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];

    Uploader *uploader = [[Uploader alloc] init];
    uploader.parameters = @{@"apikey": @"123", @"scope": @"asd"};
    [uploader upload];

    [runLoop run];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I Did the change. But same response.

Comment: Same Result after i add content type for the data.

Comment: See my second edit. Just tried with a quick python script and a console app. Looks like the problem might be on the server-side.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://210.7.64.98/360videos/webservices/devicetoken.php"];
NSDictionary *postDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:devToken1, @"token",
                          @"iphone", @"device_type", nil];
NSData *postData = [self encodeDictionary:postDict];

// Create the request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", postData.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];




dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // Peform the request
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *receivedData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                                 returningResponse:&response
                                                             error:&error];
    if (error) {
        // Deal with your error
        if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
            NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
            NSLog(@"HTTP Error: %d %@", httpResponse.statusCode, error);
            return;
        }
        NSLog(@"Error %@", error);
        return;
    }


    NSString *responeString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData
                                                    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"token Response : %@",responeString);
});
```

//here is encode method

- (NSData*)encodeDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary {
  NSMutableArray *parts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  for (NSString *key in dictionary) {
      NSString *encodedValue = [[dictionary objectForKey:key] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      NSString *encodedKey = [key stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
      NSString *part = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@=%@", encodedKey, encodedValue];
      [parts addObject:part];
  }
  NSString *encodedDictionary = [parts componentsJoinedByString:@"&"];
  return [encodedDictionary dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  }
  //may be this will help full for you.