# iOS sending picture to a server via HTTP POST

Tags: ios, http, post, nsurlconnection, nsurl

I need to send a pic to a server via HTTP post, but I am getting a response from server saying that I used POST+GET. Any ideas what I did wrong? Here is my code.

```
- (void)sendMessagesWithImg
{
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    UIImage *imgColor = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imgbar.png"];



        UIImage * imageToPost = [[UIImage alloc] init];

       imageToPost = [self convertImageToGrayScale:imgColor];

        // add image data
        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToPost, 1.0);
       if (imageData) {

            [body appendData:imageData];

       }

    [imgView setImage:imageToPost];

    [body appendData:imageData];


      NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"URL"]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [conn start];   
}
```

Server response

> More than the maximum number of request parameters (GET plus POST) for
>   a single request ([512]) were detected.

Answer (score 0):

You append the imageData for two times. Delete the second.

```
[body appendData:imageData];
```

In any case try also with this:

```
// set the content-length
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
```

and read this post..you have to attach others parameters probably:

[ios Upload Image and Text using HTTP POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564833/ios-upload-image-and-text-using-http-post)

Comment: Thanks.I fixed that but I still get the error. any other mistakes you see?