# Uploading image to tomcat server leas to error 400 in ios

Tags: ios, tomcat, nsurlconnection, multipartform-data, nsurlrequest

When i am trying to upload image to server(tomcat)it is showing an error 400 as shown below
  Response is Apache Tomcat/7.0.22 - Error report

## HTTP Status 400 -

**type** Status report

**message**

**description** The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ().

#### Apache Tomcat/7.0.22

if i send null in the space of image i am getting response correctly, The code in the BB works fine can any one help me please stuck with this from past two days

Code for iOS

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL   URLWithString:@"http://api.domain.com:8080/Saldos/api/saldos/subirFoto"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backGb.png"];
NSMutableData *bodyData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];// backGb.jpg
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pic"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:imageData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

[bodyData appendData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 9)];

[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
[request setValue:@"text/html,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/jpeg,*/*;q=0.5" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"backGb.png" forHTTPHeaderField:@"pic"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:bodyData];
NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Code in BB:

```
httpConnection = MakeUrl.returnUrl(url);
httpConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);

 httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
  HttpProtocolConstants.CONTENT_TYPE_MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
httpConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux "+ "i686; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20061201 Firefox/2.0.0.6 (Ubuntu-feisty)");
 httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept","text/html,application/xml,"+ "application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/jpg,*/*;q=0.5");
 httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

  URLEncodedPostData _postData = new URLEncodedPostData("UTF-8",false);
 _postData.append("pic", postData);
OutputStream os = httpConnection.openOutputStream();
os.write(_postData.getBytes());
os.flush();
```

Comment: refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564833/ios-upload-image-and-text-using-http-post

Comment: @Danyun That doesnot work in my case

Comment: Is there any special need for you case? Multi-form is a http standard to upload image.

Comment: When i tried to send using multipart i got this error " The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method ()."