# How to upload different types files to the server in ios?

Tags: ios, web-services, ios7

In my application to allow the user to select file/s to upload to my server.  i will have a list of compatible file types, .pdf .doc .pages etc.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your question is not specific. What you want? Specific file selection or how to upload it on server? Also you should post your efforts that what have you done so far?

Comment: In my Application, the user need to go to  folder(where all files are stored) and after send selected file to server  when user is selecting choose file button . i am getting images files by using uipickerviewcontroller but i don't know how to select other files.

Answer (score 0):

For getting the file type:

```
[yourFilePath pathExtension];
```

From this you can check what type of file it is.

For uploading Once I got a solution in SO (forget to store the URL. :S). This:

```
// create request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];                                    
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[request setTimeoutInterval:30];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// set Content-Type in HTTP header
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

// post body
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

// add params (all params are strings)
for (NSString *param in _params) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [_params objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

// add image data
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToPost, 1.0);
if (imageData) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n", FileParamConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:imageData];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];

// set the content-length
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

// set URL
[request setURL:requestURL];
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Here is the link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564833/ios-upload-image-and-text-using-http-post