# iOS 8 SDK: modal UIWebView and camera/image picker

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uiwebview, uiimagepickercontroller

I have found that, when compiling for iOS 8 (and running in iOS 8), a `UIWebView` cannot show the camera/image picker if the `UIWebView` is in a view controller presented modally. It works without problem in view controllers directly “hanging” from the window `rootViewController` or view controllers pushed from it.

The test application can be found at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6214425/TestModalWebCamera.zip but I will describe it below.

My test application (built with storyboards, but the real application doesn’t use them) has two view controllers (unoriginally named `ViewController` and `ViewController2`). `ViewController` is contained in a `UINavigationController` which is the root view controller. `ViewController` contains a `UIWebView` (works OK), a button that “shows” (“pushes”) `ViewController2`, and a `UIBarButtonItem` which modally presents `ViewController2`. `ViewController2` has another `UIWebView` which works when “pushed” but not when “presented”.

Both `ViewController` and `ViewController2` are loaded with:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  [self.webView loadHTMLString:@"<input type=\"file\" accept=\"image/*;capture=camera\">" baseURL:nil];
}
```

When trying to use the modal `UIWebView` Xcode prints the following in the console and dismisses the app modal:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIImagePickerController: 0x150ab800> on <ViewController2: 0x14623580> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

My current theory is that the changes in `UIActionSheet` to `UIAlertController` might have produced this situation, but it’s quite hard to prove. I will open a Radar with Apple, just in case.

Has someone found the same situation and some workaround?

Comment: Currently in the same boat and have not yet found a workaround. The app I'm working on was working fine in iOS 7 but is behaving like you describe in iOS 8. I put a bounty on this question in the hope that it will get more attention.

Comment: First of all, input file is broken on safari iOS 8, it doesn't upload anything, it's a bug and will be fixed on next updates. But I don't have your problem, my app just crash when I tap the input file button and select the type (camera or photo library, it doesn't matter)

Comment: Same here. The problem happens when the webview is inside a controller presented as a Modal. I'm trying to figure out a workaound. Still works on iOS 7, but not iOS 8.

Comment: I have requested a technical support with Apple

Comment: I've just tested and the bug is still present on 8.0.2, it works on the original view controller, on the pushed view controller, but not on the modal view controller.

Comment: Same problem here, still not solved in 8.0.2

Comment: Bug is actual for 8.1.3.

Comment: still present in iOS 9

Comment: ive found this with iOS 10.2 today on iPAD

Comment: Continues to be an issue with iOS 10. Note this happens if you are using a UIWebView or WKWebView.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I found that in iOS 8.0.2 iPad does not seem to have that bug but iPhone still does.

However, overriding following in the view controller containing the uiwebview

```
-(void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion
```

And checking that there is a presentedViewController seems to work.

But need to check side effects

```
#import "UiWebViewVC.h"

@interface UiWebViewVC ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *uiwebview;

@end

@implementation UiWebViewVC

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://html5demos.com/file-api-simple"];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    self.uiwebview.scalesPageToFit = YES;

    [self.uiwebview loadRequest:request];
}


-(void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion
{
    if ( self.presentedViewController)
    {
        [super dismissViewControllerAnimated:flag completion:completion];
    }
}


@end
```

Comment: Seems to be a good workaround. Thank you very much. Can I ask how you end up with this solution?

Comment: The uiwebview causes the uialertcontroller to be presented on the uiwebviewviewcontroller to show the camera/existing/cancel. When user chooses option, then uialertcontroller is meant to be dismissed and the uuiimagepickercontroller presented.  However the dismissing of the uialertcontroller seems to fire twice.  The first time is ok because the presentedviewcontroller = the uialertcontroller , but the 2nd time the presentedviewcontroller property is nil, and this causes the dismissviewcontrolleranimated method to kill the webviewviewcontroller which is the problem, to I now test for this case

Comment: This solved it for me. However remember, if you're presenting your custom UIWebViewController (or WKWebViewController for that matter) inside a UINavigationController, remember this needs to go in there instead. So just make a subclass of UINavigationController and dump this code in there instead.

Comment: Well, I'm having the same issue, but I'm on Xamarin Studio. I managed to do something like this:

[http://pastebin.com/q6Zm8Gii](http://pastebin.com/q6Zm8Gii)

but instead of my view closing on input button click, It closes when I click on one of the "take a picture" or "select an existing picture" button. This is anoying.

Comment: I tought this may be related to [ios-8-0-uiwebview-file-input-crashes-my-app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25898564/ios-8-0-uiwebview-file-input-crashes-my-app), but changing the deployment target from `7.0` to `8.1` or `8.0` did absolutly nothing. Works fine in simulator tho. Screw this and don't use webviews.

Comment: Be aware that adding above check will block dismissing this very view controller if it itself presented as modal. In my case it presented by modal segue and above check blocking dismissing it. I fix it by adding following dirty check: `if (self.presentedViewController||!completion)`. It works for me because I always pass `nil` to `completion`. Alternative solution is to use special flag to indicate that this very controller about to be dismissed.

Comment: The same problem came to my app on iOS 8. This code snippet works for me.

Comment: could this workaround be applied to the cordova inappbrowser?
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/tree/master/src/ios
I can't upload images on iOS8 iphones but it works on iOS7 + iOS8 iPads ... unfortunately I don't know objective C

Comment: possibly.  you would need to insert the following at line 724 at https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/src/ios/CDVInAppBrowser.m (void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion
{
    if ( self.presentedViewController)
    {
        [super dismissViewControllerAnimated:flag completion:completion];
    }
}

Comment: thanks, doing this + adding the attribute "multiple" to the html input element finally made it work for me

Comment: @Riesling Thanks for your input. The solution you provided made it to work for me too, but it doesn't provide an option of "Take photo", instead it directly goes to your photos. Is it the same for you?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. And I didn't find a workaround so far, so I guess I need to live with that until the bug is fixed.

Comment: I actually don't want the user to select more than 1 image. :( If you find any other solution please post it here. Thanks!!

Comment: @Riesling Hey make sure you add the code in CDVInAppBrowserNavigationController and not in CDVInAppBrowser. You won't need to add the Multiple attribute and it would work fine. :)

Comment: Very great solution, i wish i can give you +100

Comment: Nice one, seeinvisible. You saved me a lot of time. Please pay attention to what @Baza207 said, as it was exactly my case.

Comment: not working if web view controller is called using push view ! any luck for me?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation on why this error occurred. Swift 3.1 update to the override method

override func dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: ((_: Void) -> Void)?)
    {
        if presentedViewController != nil
        {
            super.dismiss(animated: flag, completion: completion)
        }
        else
        {
            print("\n Error Check")
        }
    }

Comment: Dude you may have saved me from a lot of hair loss today

Comment: This is working fine for me and able to load photo/camera , but I am triggering action on second page of webview and after selection of photo it redirects me to home page of webview instead of page from where I load gallary. Any idea on that?

Answer (score 7):

I have the same issue on iOS 9. Try to add ivar '_flag' and then override this methods in view controller with UIWebView

```
#pragma mark - Avoiding iOS bug

- (UIViewController *)presentingViewController {

    // Avoiding iOS bug. UIWebView with file input doesn't work in modal view controller

    if (_flagged) {
        return nil;
    } else {
       return [super presentingViewController];
    }
}

- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion {

    // Avoiding iOS bug. UIWebView with file input doesn't work in modal view controller

    if ([viewControllerToPresent isKindOfClass:[UIDocumentMenuViewController class]]
    ||[viewControllerToPresent isKindOfClass:[UIImagePickerController class]]) {
        _flagged = YES;
    }

    [super presentViewController:viewControllerToPresent animated:flag completion:completion];
}

- (void)trueDismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion {

    // Avoiding iOS bug. UIWebView with file input doesn't work in modal view controller

    _flagged = NO;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:flag completion:completion];
}
```

This works for me fine

Comment: what is `trueDismissViewController` ? And should I add this in the first View Controller or the Modal View controller?

Comment: `trueDismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` is what you should use in this class when you need to dismiss, rather than calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` which will not work.

Answer (score 2):

For me I tend to have a custom UINavigationController so that multiple views can share the same logic. So for my workaround (in Swift) here is what I put in my custom NavigationController.

```
import UIKit

class NavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func dismissViewControllerAnimated(flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?) {
        if let vc = self.presentedViewController {
            // don't bother dismissing if the view controller being presented is a doc/image picker
            if !vc.isKindOfClass(UIDocumentMenuViewController) || !vc.isKindOfClass(UIImagePickerController) {
                super.dismissViewControllerAnimated(flag, completion:completion)
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // make sure that the navigation controller can't be dismissed
        self.view.window?.rootViewController = self
    }
}
```

This means that you can have loads of view controllers with webviews and they'll all work with the file upload element.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue, and I have discovered that the UIWebView elements in IOS do not support the html element:

I am not sure why Apple chose to not support this IMPORTANT html element, but I am sure they have their reasons. (Even though this element works perfectly on Safari on IOS.)

In many cases, when the user clicks this kind of button in a UIWebView, it will let them take/ choose a photo. HOWEVER, the UIWebView in IOS does not have the capability to attach files like this into the POST data when the form is submitted.

The Solution: To accomplish the same task you can create a similar form in InterfaceBuilder with a button that triggers the UIImagePickerController. Then, you create you an HTTP POST request with all of the form data and the image. It isn't as hard as it sounds, check out the link below for some sample code that gets the job done: [ios Upload Image and Text using HTTP POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564833/ios-upload-image-and-text-using-http-post)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, here's the workaround I ended up using. It's a 2 minute change, pretty hacky, but works as expected and avoids the bug we're all having. Basically, rather than presenting the child view controller modally, I set it to the window's rootViewController and keep a reference to the parent controller. So where I used to have this (in parent view controller):

```
presentViewController(newController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I now have this

```
view.window?.rootViewController = newController
```

In both cases, the parent controller is `newController`'s delegate, which is how I keep the reference.

```
newController.delegate = self
```

Finally, where in my delegate callback for closing the modal, where I used to have this:

```
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

I now have this:

```
viewController.view.window?.rootViewController = self
```

So we get the same effect of a view controller taking over the screen entirely, then yielding its control when it's done. In this case though, it's not animated. I have a feeling animating the controller transition wouldn't be very hard with some of the built in view animations.

Hopefully you're already using the delegate pattern to manage communication with the modal controller, per Apple's recommendation, but if you're not I'm sure you can use any number of methods that keep a reference and get called back.

Comment: as you say, it's a workaround, you know there is a bug when the view is modal and then you make it the root view controller instead of presenting it modally. But as you say, there is no anymation, and in case you are in the iPad and you don't want to present it full screen, with your workaround isn't possible. You could just push the view controller and you'll have the same effect but with a slide animation

Comment: @jcesarmobile yeah, not exactly happy with it, but at least it let's us distribute our app. Great point regarding iPad. We're iPhone only so I hadn't considered it. Actually, I wonder if the bug even happens on iPad?

Comment: This doesn't seem to happen on android, but I'm having this issue on iOS 8.1 with xamarin and I didn't manage to code your workaround on xamarin :(.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to create custom View Controller with custom modal presentation based on controllers child-parent hierarchy. Animation will be the same so the user will not notice the difference.

My suggestions for animation:

```
animateWithDuration:(animated ? 0.6 : 0.0)
                      delay:0.0
     usingSpringWithDamping:1.f
      initialSpringVelocity:0.6f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
```

It will look exactly like default modal presentation animation in iOS7/8.

Answer (score 0):

What I did what every time the view controller is change, convert the destination view in root.

from first view controller:

```
let web = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"web") as! UINavigationController

view.window?.rootViewController = web
```

this is how I pass the root to the other, and when comeback to the first one I made this.

from web view controller:

```
let first = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "reveal") as! SWRevealViewController
    present(first, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and everything is fine, I can show the modal for select photo from library, take photo and everything else.

I don't know if that is a good practice but works fine in emulator and device.

Hope it helps.