# Upload photo with UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I would like to upload a photo directly from UIWebView that has a HTML form for file upload. When I click on button I get options to take photo or choose existing. But when I click any of these two options I get

> Warning: Attempt to present `<UIImagePickerController: 0x15c15e00>` on `<UINavigationController: 0x155a2660>` whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Could please anyone can explain me these warning...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug on iOS 8, that happens when the webview is presented modally.

The only options right now it not to present the webview modally, you can present it with a navigation controller or switching the rootviewcontroller

Here you can read more about the bug and a proposed solution

[iOS 8 SDK: modal UIWebView and camera/image picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25942676/ios-8-sdk-modal-uiwebview-and-camera-image-picker)