# Webview - Best way to upload images from device

Tags: android, ios, image, webview, image-uploading

I currently have apps on google play and itunes, which are native wrappers to a shared webview. The beauty of the webview is I can make changes on the webview side and they will immediately be viewable on any device, however I am having issues with being able to upload images from user's albums/galleries stored on their device.

What, if any, is the fastest implementation, using my current webview strategy, to allow users to upload images from their device's native albums/galleries?

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26376940/upload-photo-with-uiwebview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the standard **file input type**:

```
<form action="/server/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

This should work out of the box on iOS6+ and bring up native open file dialog, but you will have to do some coding on Android.

On olders platforms there is a workaround to use unofficial api (`WebChromeClient #openFileChooser`) but Google broke this in KitKat and then released official support for this feature in Lollipop with `WebChromeClient.html#onShowFileChooser`. So, KitKat will probably remain broken, but on other platforms it should work fine.

Please see this Android bug report Issue [62220](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62220).

You can implement this yourself (look at [this](http://androidexample.com/Open_File_Chooser_With_Camera_Option_In_Webview_File_Option/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=128&aaid=148) example), but if you're looking for a WebView subclass that "just works", you may want to try [Android-AdvancedWebView](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView) project.

Another option, or just as a fix for KitKat devices, is to have the native wrapper encode the file as **Base64 String** and then the HTML app could send it to the server.