# On UIWebView not able to select photo?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview, uiimagepickercontroller

I am loading URL on UIWebView on that URL photo select option is there, when I click on "choose file" photo select alert will come like
below in image :---
/Users/ArjunSinghBaghel/Desktop/Screen Shot 2017-02-13 at 11.06.02 PM.png

but when I click on "Photo Library" that page going to disappear.

Please help my out ..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Correct your screenshot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to set proper permissions in `Info.plist` file. Namely `Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description` and `Privacy - Camera Library Usage Description`.

Alternatively, you can use `WKWebView`. I just tested Swift implementation in Swift Playgrounds on my iPad with IOS 10 and it is working fine. Please see https://gist.github.com/kiritmodi2702/b8a674bb66803c1397cab55030ae2c54.

Comment: I already added both things , its happening in iOS10 and its giving waring --

Warning: Attempt to present <UIImagePickerController: 0x150ab800> on <ViewController: 0x14623580> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: Although it is for IOS 8, looks similar to your problem - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26376940/upload-photo-with-uiwebview?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26376940/upload-photo-with-uiwebview?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

As the warning logged in debugger suggests, the `UIImagePickerController` is not getting invoked appropriately.
Consider the example,

```
- (void)takePhoto:(UIButton *)sender{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil]; 
}
```

Confirm whether the `self` being used is a subclass of `UIViewController` which has been added to the `UINavigatorController Bar` stack.
 In the current scenario, it appears `self` is a `UIView` instance.