# WebView select file from photo library

Tags: ios, swift, webview, segue

I'm working on a project where I'm using 2 views, `MainView` and `SecondView`.
`MainView` is more or less a start pages and then I use the segue function to go from `MainView` to `SecondView`.

In `SecondView` I have `WebView` and on this website I have a file uploader. So the user should be able to upload images from his or her photo library to the site.

The website is accessed with this code:

```
if let url = NSURL(string: "https://example.com/uploader") {
        webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
    }
```

The problem is that when I try to upload an image it only segues back to my `MainView`

[image]

So when I press Photo Library it segues back to MainView.

However I recreated the WebView version of the app in a new project with only one view and then everything works like a charm as shown below

[image]

So basically my question is, how do I prevent the app from segueing back when I select Photo Library?

Link to
[Download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ngqg8dyye4z9ipf/URLSegue.zip?dl=0) the project and see for yourself.

Comment: Can you post the code being used to select the photo from the photo library?

Comment: This is completely done from the website. Using Wordpress and Contact Form 7 plugin with the file upload feature.

Comment: I think if you dint 'self.navigationController?.pushViewController' and used 'present' some how if using pushviewcontroller. it will go back to your rootviewcontroller. hence i make a Present view. and make custom Title for the webview

Comment: Is there a way to handle selection of file type within the code? Or manipulate what file type should get selected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was dealing with this issue for a while when I was working more often with `ViewControllers`.

Adding this following code to the `ViewController` with the `WebView` does solve the problem in the iOS Simulator.

```
override func dismissViewControllerAnimated(flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?) 
{
    if self.presentedViewController != nil {
        super.dismissViewControllerAnimated(flag, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

However, I still had the problem when running on an actual device. To fix it, I added that code in the `MainViewController` as well.

Hope this solves it and happy coding.

Comment: but how am i going to used " self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)" seem like i cant use it at all this view controller

Answer (score 3):

I tried using Sasha Nicolas' hack but it won't work right now with the new Swift Version. I'm using Swift 4 right now. Xcode gave me some hints and this is what worked fine.

```
override func dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?) {
    if self.presentedViewController != nil {
        super.dismiss(animated: flag, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

I placed it at the very end of my view controller code, just before the `}` of my main class.

Don't forget to **add permissions** for camera and photos in `info.plist` and this code at the beginning of you class in you view controller.

```
class ViewControllerLogado: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {}
```

Comment: after uploading file is your web view reload again? I've checked with real device and simulator. Simulator working fine but In real device it reloading.

Answer (score 2):

A fast workaround for this is to add the following code to the ViewController with the WebView:

```
override func dismissViewControllerAnimated(flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?) {
    if self.presentedViewController != nil {
        super.dismissViewControllerAnimated(flag, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

This post is related to your question:
[iOS 8 SDK: modal UIWebView and camera/image picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25942676/ios-8-sdk-modal-uiwebview-and-camera-image-picker)

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift 3.0**

```
override func dismissViewControllerAnimated(flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?) 
{
    if self.presentedViewController != nil 
    {
       super.dismiss(animated: flag, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this

NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription to the info.plist file

and the description of how the file to be used. it works for me with the Xcode 8.2.1