# Xamarin Forms - Camera and Image Picker doesnt work when using Modal Popup

Tags: image, xamarin, camera, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin forms app, that loads a camera and image selector, when I use it in a page they both work fine, however when I am in a page and then use a modal popup to display the same page the links  to the camera / image selector does nothing.

I get this error in the Output window in Visual Studio

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIImagePickerController: 0x1276b2400> on 
<Xamarin_Forms_Platform_iOS_PlatformRenderer: 0x128678400> whose view is 
not in the window hierarchy!
```

I am updated to 4.2.0.719 Xamarin and Xamarin.iOS 10.2.0.4

Anyone have any ideas to get around this in Xamarin Forms ?

I notice a post regarding iOS [iOS 8 SDK: modal UIWebView and camera/image picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25942676/ios-8-sdk-modal-uiwebview-and-camera-image-picker) but this is not for Zamarin ?

Answer (score 1):

I recall having come across a similar issue before and filed a bug report: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44500

> Bug 44500 - A WebView that has a file picker control fails to show photo picker when page is pushed modally.
>
> Description
>
> A ContentPage with WebView that has a file picker control fails to show photo picker when ContentPage is pushed modally. This warning is displayed when the WebView tries to open the UIImagePickerController:
>
> Warning: Attempt to present <UIImagePickerController: 0x7ba68800> on <Xamarin_Forms_Platform_iOS_ModalWrapper: 0x7e379c90> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
>
> Works as expected when page with WebView is pushed non-modally.

Comment: This is the problem I have, did you ever get it working ? see there is no response ? I need mine in a Modal view.