# How do you get the SurveyMonkey SDK to upload images on iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, surveymonkey

We are trying to integrate the SurveyMonkey SDK with our iOS app and Android app for user feedback. Everything seems to be working, except we are unable to upload images from photo library/camera on both platforms. Upon attempting to upload, the SDK becomes unresponsive, or it returns directly to the app without submitting the response. However, if you submit without trying to upload a photo from the library, the response will be accepted.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Show us your code; post the versions you use. Did you checked the access rights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derek, I'm an engineer who works on the SDKs for SurveyMonkey. Unfortunately file upload is not yet supported by the iOS/Android SDKs. We're working on adding support in Android, but iOS will remain unsupported for the time being due to a known issue in [iOS UIWebviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25942676/ios-8-sdk-modal-uiwebview-and-camera-image-picker).

Wish I had a better answer for you, but stay tuned.