# How to post a picture from iPhone app (in Swift) to MySQL database?

Tags: php, ios, mysql, iphone, swift

I am trying to have users upload on imagine on the app I am developing for a class with Swift and posting it to my MySQL database with PHP but have no idea how to do this. I cannot find any sort of source code online for this and am at a loss for trying this myself.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: No, but if I had to I would use a search engine to find out (hint, hint). `;-)`

Comment: [Possible useful link](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/67141-sending-uiimage-to-mysql.html) and [another one](http://iphoneblogsdk.blogspot.co.uk/2014/06/uploading-image-to-mysql-from-ios-using.html) from [this search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=iphone+send+image+to+mysql).

Answer (score 2):

Though you can technically store images in a MySQL database, it's really bad practice.

Instead, you'll want to store the file in a disk directory. Since this is a broad question with an almost limitless amount of ways you could achieve your goal, here's one suggestion:

1. Send the file as [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564833/ios-upload-image-and-text-using-http-post) data to your server.
2. [Store](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) the file using PHP.

Comment: Yes, good point about (not) storing images in a database. Once you get to a certain size, it makes the database slow in operation and backups are a pain to handle.