# How to send number of images to server using JSON Array in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, afnetworking

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

NSString *imagePostUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.abc.com?"];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"device_id":string,@"device_phone":[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"SerialNumber"]};

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:imagePostUrl parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:data name:@"uploaded_file" fileName:ext mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
}];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [manager HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success: ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"response: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
op.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:op];
```

I am getting images from image in images path in mobile , I am sending all the images with parameters to the server. Here sending images are one by one with parameters to the server hoe can i send this .
How can I achieve this? Please help me.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: We cannot help unless you show the code you wrote.  And we need to know what error you received when it doesn't work. Also, when is the server-side written in?  Are you using FTP or HTTP as transport?  You need a lot more details in your question for anyone to help you.

Comment: Please submit your code and what you did so we can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,

I would suggest the same.

`AFNetworking` will do that for you like this:

```
-(void)uploadPhoto{
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://server.url"]];

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.avatarView.image, 0.5);

    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"username": self.username, @"password" : self.password};

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [manager POST:@"rest.of.url" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        //do not put image inside parameters dictionary as I did, but append it!
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:paramNameForImage fileName:@"photo.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Success: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, error);
    }];
    [op start];
}
```

Comment: Your welcome Guru. :)

Answer (score 0):

A normal way to upload images is to use a multi-part form encoding. Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8567771/4185345) about uploading images using `multi-part form data`. If you use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), it could be done with [Multi-Part Request](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#post-multi-part-request).

With JSON you could use a simple base64 encoded strings:

```
UIImage *image  = [[UIImage alloc] init]; //your image here
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSString *base64string = [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
```

Do this for every image and send an array of strings in JSON format. On the server side you need to decode this strings to images. But it is **not** a good solution.