# How to send an HTTP request with multipart data containing a json string and a big file from the file system?

Tags: ios, http, nsurlrequest, nsinputstream

---

### Context

I want to send an HTTP request with multipart body data composed by two segments:

1. A JSON string containing some metadata
2. Some file binary data

---

### What I already know

This can be done easily as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8567771/4681266). But what happens in a situation where the file can be potentially large? With this new constraint, we naturally can't encapsulate the data in a `NSData` object, as it would take a lot of memory resources.

The first idea that anyone familiar with the `NSURLRequest` class would have is to use the `HTTPBodyStream` property instead of `HTTPBody`. But how is it possible to get a stream that would write both JSON and file data segments (as well as the boundaries and the other required HTTP stuff)?

The way out would be to subclass `NSInputStream`. In fact I've noticed that the AFNetworking framework uses this approach. But from I've heard, there are a lot of undocumented/weird methods to override from the `NSStream` class, as described [here](http://blog.bjhomer.com/2011/04/subclassing-nsinputstream.html), which, in my humble opinion, sounds like a lot of (potentially dangerous) work needed to achieve something apparently simple.

---

### Question

Is there a way to achieve the desired behaviour? Please consider the following constraints:

- No third party frameworks
- Using a clean method (not overriding undocumented methods, as they can change on future SDKs)

Answer (score 1):

You can use my open sourced [POSInputStreamLibrary](https://github.com/pavelosipov/POSInputStreamLibrary). It provides ability to stream any data you want. The only thing you need to do is to implement [POSBlobInputStreamDataSource](https://github.com/pavelosipov/POSInputStreamLibrary/blob/master/POSInputStreamLibrary/POSBlobInputStreamDataSource.h) protocol and use implementation as an argument of [POSBlobInputStream](https://github.com/pavelosipov/POSInputStreamLibrary/blob/master/POSInputStreamLibrary/POSBlobInputStream.h).

If you strongly restricted using 3rd party frameworks you can use [POSBlobInputStream](https://github.com/pavelosipov/POSInputStreamLibrary/blob/master/POSInputStreamLibrary/POSBlobInputStream.h) as an example which implements private API methods to make custom NSInputStream workable.

Feel free to ask any questions about implemetation details and good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This looks like an interesting approach and I guess it would solve my problems. But I was taking a look at your POSBlobInputStream class implementation and found that you haven't implemented the '_scheduleInCFRunLoop:forMode:', '_setCFClientFlags:callback:context:' and '_unscheduleFromCFRunLoop:forMode:' methods. These are the 'dangerous undocumented' methods that I mentioned in my question. From what I've read in this link: http://blog.bjhomer.com/2011/04/subclassing-nsinputstream.html they can cause the app to crash

Comment: But of course, I haven't implemented anything yet. From your experience, do you think that NSInputStream subclasses should work properly without implementing these methods?

Comment: Thanks for a question, @GabrielHuff. The magic is in the method `resolveInstanceMethod:`. It cuts '_' prefix in incomming unknown selectors and tries to redirect invokation to the methods without it. You can look at companions of `_scheduleInCFRunLoop:forMode:`, `_setCFClientFlags:callback:context:` and `_unscheduleFromCFRunLoop:forMode:` without underscore in [POSBlobInputStream.m](https://github.com/pavelosipov/POSInputStreamLibrary/blob/master/POSInputStreamLibrary/POSBlobInputStream.m)