# Why AFNetworking taking too much time(86sec) to upload image(2mb)

Tags: php, ios, iphone, codeigniter

Code working properly but taking too much time to upload image. Am not able to understand why its happen ?. It may be server side or need to check in

**my code**

```
AFHTTPClient *client= [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:BaseUrl]];
```

Need help

Comment: The code you quoted is most definitely not the whole code used to perform the upload...

Comment: You haven't told use anything about the speed of your Internet connection. If you use some kind of *DSL or cable connection, it is quite frequent that upload speeds are a lot slower than download speeds. What upload speeds are you getting with other devices/to other sites using the same Internet connection?

Comment: I would like to suggest you to upload image using multipart, since it is much faster and helpful for sending large data. This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564833/ios-upload-image-and-text-using-http-post might help you to better understand

Answer (score 0):

File upload is bit high to system. Bcz it has to ***validate*** then add those in ***temp upload path*** then finally ***upload it*** to main folder. So it will take some time with the few manner.

1. Internet Speed.
2. File size
3. PHP Memory size

Comment: Any process to increase the uploading speed ?

Comment: I dont think so. Leave it has it is check this [article as well](http://www.vbulletin.com/forum/forum/customizing-vbulletin/vbulletin-templates-graphics-styles/301785-how-can-i-increase-the-uploading-attachment-speed)

Comment: @MujaheedSayyed any response??

Comment: Sorry for late reply ....am all-ready done this changes in my server "php.ini" file...but there is no progress....is still taking time