# Any examples using carrierwave/carrierwave_direct in order to build a JSON API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-api

Building a JSON API (gem rails-api) and using rails 4.2.4 I would like to know whether you can recommend some projects (github, websites...) on fileUpload (I insist for API-ONLY-APP ) as examples that I can use to help me ?

Comment: Please explain more about this file upload, in what way do you want to receive the files? (data field in the api, url, etc?)

Comment: I'm building this API to serve an mobile app (iOS/Android). this will allow the users to upload photos and small videos. at this moment, one of my model have 1 field for a picture.

Comment: I think I would rather upload files directly to s3 and then post process them on the server. I will look for another solution though.

Comment: yes, that is why I wanted to used the gem carrierwave_direct (allow direct upload to S3) which is on the top of gem carrierwave. another solution than carrierwave ? please check your twitter.

Comment: Your question is more about how to upload a file to API from iOS than how to handle it server side I think. On the server side you just need to tell carrier wave in which argument to expect the file. iOS example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564833/ios-upload-image-and-text-using-http-post

Comment: the thing is the app (android/iOS) is not done yet. I'm really at begining the of the project and want a global and more experienced vision of how to do it. May I have your mail please so that we can discuss more about it if you don't mind ?