# How Post images on Imgur users line

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest, imgur

I work under the application that should allow to post images on users wall. 
At the beginning he is getting authorised,  at this stage everything is ok. But when I am trying to make a post request - nothing is posted. could you just help to solve the next issue. 
When user select an image and press post button:

```
- (void) postActionSelected
{

    NSString *title = [[self titleTextField] text];
    NSString *description = [[self commentTextField] text];

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.currentImage.image, 0.5);
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{



    [imgurServerManager uploadPhoto:imageData
                           title:title
                     description:description
                 completionBlock:^(NSString *result) {
                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
                     });
                 } failureBlock:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error, NSInteger status) {
                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
                         [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Upload Failed"
                                                     message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (Status code %ld)", [error localizedDescription], (long)status]
                                                    delegate:nil
                                           cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                           otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil] show];
                     });
                 }];

});
```

}

and then in `ImGurServerManager` this post should be done:

```
+ (void)uploadPhoto:(NSData*)imageData
              title:(NSString*)title
        description:(NSString*)description
    completionBlock:(void(^)(NSString* result))completion
       failureBlock:(void(^)(NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error, NSInteger status))failureBlock
{
    NSAssert(imageData, @"Image data is required");
    //NSAssert(access_token, @"Access token is required");

    NSString *urlString = @"https://api.imgur.com/3/upload";
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSMutableData *requestBody = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------0983745982375409872438752038475287";

    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    //[request addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"access_token %@", access_token] forHTTPHeaderField:@"access_token"];

    [requestBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary]
          dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [requestBody appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"image\"; filename=\".tiff\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [requestBody appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [requestBody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [requestBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    if (title) {
        [requestBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [requestBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"title\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [requestBody appendData:[title dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [requestBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }


    if (description) {
        [requestBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [requestBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"description\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [requestBody appendData:[description dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [requestBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }

    [requestBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] 
          dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request setHTTPBody:requestBody];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
        if ([responseDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"data.error"]) {
            if (failureBlock) {
                if (!error) {

                    error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"imguruploader" code:10000 userInfo:@{NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey : [responseDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"data.error"]}];
                }
                failureBlock(response, error, [[responseDictionary valueForKey:@"status"] intValue]);
            }
        } else {
            if (completion) {
                completion([responseDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"data.link"]);
            }

        }

    }];
}
```

I suppose that the reason here is that I missed some additional parameter, but I am totally lost with it.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally image is uploaded, main reason for not posting it wasn't defining access_token:

```
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", token] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

and deleting Dictionary with parameters, in case of post requests on Imgur- it is not necessary.

- (void)uploadPhoto:(NSData*)imageData
                title:(NSString*)title
          description:(NSString*)description
         access_token:(NSString*)token
                topic:(NSString*) topic
      completionBlock:(void(^)(NSString* result))completion
         failureBlock:(void(^)(NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error, NSInteger status))failureBlock
  {
      NSAssert(imageData, @"Image data is required");

  ```
  NSString *urlString = @"https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json";
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;

  [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", token] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

  [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

  [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];

  [request setTimeoutInterval:30];
  [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

  NSMutableData *body = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

  NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------0983745982375409872438752038475287";



  NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
  [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
  ```

  form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

  ```
  if (imageData) {


      [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
      [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"image\"; filename=\".tiff\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

      [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
      [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
      [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

  }
      if (title) {
          [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
          [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"title\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
          [body appendData:[title dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
          [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
      }


      if (description) {
          [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
          [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"description\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
          [body appendData:[description dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
          [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
      }


  [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


  [request setHTTPBody:body];




  [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
      NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
      if ([responseDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"data.error"]) {
          if (failureBlock) {
              if (!error) {

                  error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"imguruploader" code:10000 userInfo:@{NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey : [responseDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"data.error"]}];
              }
              failureBlock(response, error, [[responseDictionary valueForKey:@"status"] intValue]);
          }
      } else {
          if (completion) {
              completion([responseDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"data.link"]);
          }

      }

  }];
  ```

  }

Answer (score 2):

Looking at https://api.imgur.com/endpoints/image you see that you need to perform a post with the following parameters (see: [ios Upload Image and Text using HTTP POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564833/ios-upload-image-and-text-using-http-post)):

I think you are missing the `_params[@"type"] = @"base64";`

```
// Dictionary that holds post parameters. You can set your post parameters that your server accepts or programmed to accept.
NSMutableDictionary* _params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
_params[@"type"] = @"base64";
_params[@"name"] = @"myImage";

// the boundary string : a random string, that will not repeat in post data, to separate post data fields.
NSString *BoundaryConstant = [NSString stringWithString:@"----------V2ymHFg03ehbqgZCaKO6jy"];

// create request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];                                    
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[request setTimeoutInterval:30];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// set Content-Type in HTTP header
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", BoundaryConstant];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

// post body
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

// add params (all params are strings)
for (NSString *param in _params) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [_params objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

// add image data
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToPost, 1.0);
if (imageData) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n", FileParamConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:imageData];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];

// set the content-length
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

// set URL
[request setURL:requestURL];
```

Comment: which answer do you get?

Comment: I receive next error:   Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "(null)" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.imgur.com/3/upload, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd56618eda0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1012 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFURLErrorAuthFailedResponseKey=<CFURLResponse 0x7fd566173e50 [0x10a1437b0]>{url = https://api.imgur.com/3/upload}}}, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.imgur.com/3/upload}

Comment: thanks for help) but it has no influence on posting.  It looks like in URL there a need to add account _id, just to identify, but its just my guess...