# How to post an image using multipart in NSURLSession ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-uploading, multipartform-data

Hi i am trying to upload an image through multipart to server in objective c using NSURLSession. But i am getting few errors like 
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: Header section has more than 10240 bytes (maybe it is not properly terminated)

Below is my objective c code:

{

```
NSString *boundaryConstant = @"----------V2ymHFg03ehbqgZCaKO6jy";

NSString *fileParamConstant  = @"photo";

NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data;boundary=%@",boundaryConstant];
[req setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

if (imageData) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", fileParamConstant, fileName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:imageData];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSString *bodyLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%zu",[body length]];
    [req setValue:bodyLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [req setHTTPBody:body];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration] delegate:nil delegateQueue:nil];

    NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:req fromData:body completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
          NSLog(@"STRING %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    }];
    [uploadTask resume];
}
```

}

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel ? Creating multipart requests is not easy, try the [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#creating-an-upload-task-for-a-multi-part-request-with-progress) framework which will do all the hard work for you.

Comment: I think error is related to server side. ask you server guy to increase the request header file size. that should solve your problem. your code seems fine. take a look at [ios-upload-image-and-text-using-http-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564833/ios-upload-image-and-text-using-http-post)